# How to join an array of values by returning each value as a separate string?

Tags: javascript, oracle11g

i have a stored procedure with this statement:

```sql
SELECT
  IMPORTABLEFIELDID,
  COLUMNNAME,
  SOURCETABLENAME,
  ISACTIVE
FROM IMPORTABLEFIELDS
WHERE ISACTIVE = 1
      AND lower(COLUMNNAME) in ('transferid','sendername','sendertel');
```

in my app, i have an array of column names like this:

```js
var columnNames = ['transferid', 'sendername', 'sendertel'];
```

What I am trying to get is this:

```js
var columns = "'transferid','sendername','sendertel'";
```

so that I can pass `columns` variable carrying multiple values to the where-clause of the above SQL statement.

```
var columnNames = ['transferid','sendername','sendertel'];
var columns = columnNames.join();
```

Using `.join()` method returns `"transferid,sendername,sendertel"` instead of `"'transferid','sendername','sendertel'"`

Any help?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will not work like that because the SQL `IN` operator expects a list of strings, not a string.

Instead, abandon the `IN` operator, and use the `INSTR` function. That way you can indeed make it work with a single string argument.

Assuming that your stored procedure will take a `COLUMNS` argument, you can do it as follows:

Oracle:

```
WHERE ISACTIVE = 1 and INSTR(COLUMNS, ',' || lower(COLUMNNAME) || ',') > 0
```

JavaScript:

```
columns = ',' + columnNames.join() + ',';
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to map the values to the values you want before joining.

```
var columnNames = ['transferid','sendername','sendertel']
   .map(name => "'" + name + "'");

var columns = columnNames.join(',');
```

Or in ES6:

```
const columnNames = ['transferid','sendername','sendertel']
   .map(name => `'${name}'`);

const columns = columnNames.join(',');
```

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is to add escaped single-quotes to your column names in the array. So it would look like this:

```
var columnNames = ['\'transferid\'','\'sendername\'','\'sendertel\''];
```